# How to crop and include a pdf file with specified margins, while keeping the overall page dimensions the same?

Tags: pdf, margins, pdfcrop

I want to create a document that will contain specific chapters (Introduction etc.) and I also want to add multiple pdf files within it. So far I added the pdf files and I have cropped the white margins around it as I did not want to add those and it looks great. There are 2 more things that I want to do, but everything I tried so far has failed:

1. I want to crop the pdf, but I want to keep the page dimension the same as the first 2 pages of the compiled document (see picture attached for the issue I have at the moment - for each pdf added the page dimensions change); ***Update: fixed this by deleting 'fitpaper=true'.***
2. I want to add specific margins and page numbers to the uploaded pdf files so
   that the structure is the same throughout my document.

Could you please help me with this? An example script that I used can be found below. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\title{Intro}
\author{}
\date{September 2017}

\maketitle Introduction

\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\section{Chapter 2}

\includepdf[pages=-, fitpaper=true,
            trim=12.7mm 15mm 12.7mm 0mm, clip]{Example.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=-, fitpaper=true,
            trim=15mm 17.5mm 15mm 14mm, clip]{Example_ESI.pdf}
            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't use `fitpaper` if you don't like what it does.

Comment: I feel so silly now, you just fixed my first problem. Thank you. Do you know what would be best to use to specify margins and page numbers?

Comment: pdfpages has a quite good documentation which describes lots of options to adjust margins and to add commands to an included pdf.